# Is $z=0$ an essential singularity of $z\sin(1/z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, singularity

I know the Laurent series of $z\sin(1/z)$ has infinite terms of $(1/z^k)$ at $z = 0$. The thing is:

$$\lim_{z\to 0}z\sin\frac 1 z= 0$$

So is it a removable or an essential singularity?

Comment: Why is that limit zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit applies for real arguments $x$ as $x$ approaches $0$.  But in the complex domain $z$ can approach $0$ along additional paths off the real axis, where the function grows rather than shrinking in size.  Put in $z=iy, y \rightarrow 0$, and see what happens.

Comment: Aaaah, of course, im such a dummy. Well, there goes my nice grade at complex analysis :D Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Asking just out of curiosity;how to plot $y\sin \frac{i}{y}$ as $y\to 0$ as you said

Comment: @learnmore it's just $iy\sinh(1/y)$.  Kind of boring, really.

Answer (score 1):

Since Laurent series expansion of $z\sin(1/z)$ has infinite terms of $(1/z^k)$ at $z = 0$ it is an essential singularity.

If such terms are finite then it is a pole and if no such terms, then removable singularity